# schema in Django with sqlite

Tags: django, sqlite

I am new to Django, i was going through this Django site for building up a basic app.
They have explained the procedure's to use either SQLITE3 , MYSQL, postgresql... I used SQLITE3 as they tell about it being a single large file which makes it easy to use initially.

The problem i am facing is to use .schema to check the database created. I checked certain sites which tell about using it. But i am getting stuck and i m confused to use it.

What i did was

```
$sqlite3
sqlite>.schema
sqlite>
```

This above code didnt work, then i came across a forum where they told to install a add_on to Mozilla fox, which didnt work to me as there was a compatibility issue. I even specified the path name where i have this database file located.

```
$sqlite3
sqlite> /home/ntan3/Django-1.2.3/mysite/eg_sqlite.db
```

which gave an error saying wrong syntax near '/' .

> The thing is could successfully run
>   the sample application explained by
>   the Django site.

but i wanted to see the Database created. Please Help
could anyone guide me a proper way to do it? even a specific link is also helpful. 
Thank you.

Comment: BTW: when asking a question like this, when you get to the part where "this didn't work", it's really helpful to explain exactly what did happen, and how it differed from what you expected to happen.

Comment: @Ned sorry.. i thought with the code written and then when i said it didnt work. it might have made sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basic command-line stuff. You need to pass in the path to the db file when you type sqlite3:

```
$ sqlite3 /home/ntan3/Django-1.2.3/mysite/eg_sqlite.db
```